# A function where $f(n)$ is the sum of the remainders of $n$ divided by natural numbers up to $n$.

Tags: number-theory

The question asks you to prove that there exists infinitely many $f(x) = f(x-1)$. I've conjectured that $f(2^k)=f(2^k-1)$ for positive integers $k$ but I cannot find a proof for this. I would like some help with this question.

Comment: You may be interested in [this paper](http://math.pugetsound.edu/~mspivey/RemaindersFinal.pdf) by Mike Spivey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice problem.

Sketch of solution:

To prove your conjecture, start by showing that $$  n\pmod d-(n-1)\pmod d =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $d\nmid n$ } \\
1-d, & \text{if $d\,|\,n$ }
\end{cases}$$

Where we are writing, e.g., $a\pmod b$, to denote the remainder on dividing $a$ by $b$.

(this is not difficult)

Now, letting $n=2^k$  and summing from 1 to $n-1$ we get $$F(2^k)-F(2^k-1)=\sum_{d\nmid n}1+\sum_{d\,|\,n,\,\,d<n}(1-d)=\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}-1}1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^i$$

But these sums are easily computed and we get $$(2^{k}-1)-(2^k-1)=0    $$